# Mobile phone forwards even though I've turned forwarding off

Tags: google-voice

I've got a Google Voice account that I'm using for voicemail because I like features like web based voicemail.  I am *not* using the number directly.  So I activated Google voicemail for my mobile line, but have no forwarding turned on.  But when I dial my mobile number, **NOT** my GV number, it rings a line that it is evidently being forwarded to.

I know that using Google voicemail in fact works by forwarding the call, but the weird part is that **the number it's trying to call is an old one that I removed from Google Voice**.  It's simply deleting, but Google Voice keeps forwarding to it.

Why is it doing this, and how can I make it stop?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just delete it... you need another number associated with it. I get it, you don't want the calls. You could always turn on Do-not-disturb.

The only way that I have gotten this to work is by verifying my number with another account, which it then rips from the other one because, well, it thinks that account doesn't have the rights to use that number.

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want to be able to have Google Voice as a voice mail only system, and you don't even want a Google voice number.

**That option is called Google Voice Lite. You can find out more [by clicking right here.](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/115127?hl=en)**